# Provide button to claim token without showing my private keys

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, javascript, balances

The player will claim their rewards (a token) and pay a fee through their wallet.

How does this process happen without my needing to display my private keys on the front-end?

What I know so far is that the sendSignedTransaction function transfers the tokens, but I need my private keys.

I would like to know how valid if the player can actually claim the token.

```
 web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, (err, hash) => {
        ....
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't simply give the tokens to a custom contract which has the distribution logic?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Can you indicate a path please, a tutorial, a link, to create a custom contract that has the distribution logic Happy new year and thank you very much.